# Undefined control sequence error on \fancy@reset, \f@ncyolh and \f@ncyorh when using newlfm class

Tags: newlfm, texlive-2017

I updated to TeXLive 2017 and couldn't get `newlfm.cls` to work without errors.  Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

LaTex is throwing undefined control sequence errors on `\fancy@reset`, `\f@ncyolh`, and `\f@ncyorh`.

What causes the errors?  What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `fancyhdr` package has been updated and those macros have been removed. This happens when a class/package uses internals of another package.

Comment: ...and there's technically very little need to use [`newlfm`](//ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) since everything in terms of the layout can be recreated using the default `article` class.

Comment: @egreg: thanks for the pointer.  It works now after patching `newlfm.cls` according to the new `fancyhdr` macros.  For anyone who is interested, here is a patch: https://pastebin.com/F3KcpYYJ

Comment: And the complete patched newlfm: https://pastebin.com/5bkkMEap

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Presumably the following patch (via [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) suffices:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@zfancyhead}{\fancy@reset}{\f@nch@reset}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyorh}{\f@nch@orh}{}{}
\makeatother
```

The error resulted from hard-coding package-dependent variables, which was changed in an updated release of [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). By adding the above to your preamble, the older `fancyhdr` names will be substituted for the newer names.

Comment: As of version 4.0 of `fancyhdr`, `\ps@@empty` was renamed to `\f@nch@ps@empty`, and `newlfm` also checks to make sure that `\ps@@empty` is defined. If it isn't, it throws an error. Until this is fixed, it is also necessary to put `\RequirePackage{fancyhdr} \makeatletter \let\ps@@empty\f@nch@ps@empty \makeatother` before the `\documentclass` invocation, otherwise it won't be possible to use `newlfm`.

Comment: @AdamLiter: If you have the option of using [`newlfm`](//ctan.org/pkg/newlfm), I'd probably just avoid it. You can do a similar job using `article` (with [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) and [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry)) *and* the code is more readable; the same goes for `letter`.

Comment: Agreed. I just had to recompile an old document that used it with TeX Live 2020, and I ran into this issue, so I just thought I would put this here in case anyone else runs into a similar issue and finds this information helpful.