# Error: undefined control sequence. \begin{newlfm}, but document compiles

Tags: errors, miktex, letters, newlfm

I have a lot of documents formatted like that:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,stdletter]{newlfm}
\newlfmP{addrfromleft,addrtoright,dateright,orderdatefromto,sigright,noLines}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\namefrom{Hex}
\addrfrom{Tex StackExchange}
\dateset{\today}
\addrto{Receiver}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
\textit{bla bla bla}
\\[1cm]
\begin{center}
                            {\large Title}
\end{center}
Text
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

They seem to compile correctly but i keep getting these errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@zfancyhead ...1\hbox to\headwidth {\fancy@reset
                                                  \@zfancyvbox \headheight {...
l.11 \begin{newlfm}
```

So the TeXstudio won't open the generated PDF although it is generated correctly. I am using MikTeX on Windows. **What should i do to get rid of them?** On the previous installation of TeXstudio+MikTeX, they didn't appear. I checked that i have newlfm installed in MikTeX Package Manager.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I can't reproduce the error. It works fine . Package Manager: Check again all packages. Settings(with admin and without):refresh FNBW and Update Formats.

Comment: @Bobyandbob I don't see the option to check all packages, i tried to synchronize them, refresh FNBW and update formats and it didn't help. I also uninstalled and reinstalled newlfb, no change after that. I know that it should work, because on my previous OS it did, but after reinstall it stopped.

Comment: I can confirm the error. MiKTeX updated today.

Comment: The internal macro `\fancy@reset` has recently been removed from `fancyhdr`. This already appeared here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377454/