# Problem with newlfm

Tags: letters

In fact, I want to write a cover letter with latex and I have downloaded an example , but when I compile it it shows an error, here is the code :

```
\documentclass[12pt,stdletter,orderfromtodate,sigleft]{newlfm}
\usepackage{blindtext, xfrac}

\newlfmP{dateskipbefore=50pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt}
\newlfmP{sigskipbefore=50pt}
\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}

\namefrom{Sherlock Holmes}
\addrfrom{%
 221B Baker Street\\
 London, UK
}
\addrto{%
  Basil of Baker Street\\
  221$\sfrac{1}{2}$ Baker Street\\
London, UK
}

\dateset{January 6, 1914}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}

\closeline{Sincerely,}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
\blindtext
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

an error was displayed as :

> [Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).] ) ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty" ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")) ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\epstopdf-base.sty" ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\grfext.sty" ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvdefinekeys.sty")) ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty" ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty" ("C:\Program
>   Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty")))) ! Undefined
>   control sequence. \@zfancyhead ...1\hbox to\headwidth {\fancy@reset 
>                                                     \@zfancyvbox \headheight {... l.35 \begin{newlfm}
>                       ?

Comment: I get no error. [This comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380172/error-undefined-control-sequence-beginnewlfm-but-document-compiles#comment941289_380172) might be relevant. Probably you need just an update.

Comment: It's weird is there a modification that may help because the error concerns newlfm

Comment: Try with @Werner s patch [Undefined control sequence error on \fancy@reset, \f@ncyolh and \f@ncyorh when using newlfm class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395529/124842). That solves the problem for me.

Comment: @bobyandbob how can I proceed ?

Comment: Does it help? Just add the patch like this into your code`... \closeline{Sincerely,}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@zfancyhead}{\fancy@reset}{\f@nch@reset}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyorh}{\f@nch@orh}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document} ...`

Comment: Yes it works, Thank you so very much @Bobyandbob

Comment: @Bobyandbob but there is a problem when I use \par to get the space in the next line, it doesn't seem to influence at all

Comment: I do not see a problem with `\blindtext
\par some example text`. `\par` works as expected.

Comment: But there is no space in the beginning of the paragraph