# newlfm stopped working

Tags: pdftex, fancyhdr, mactex, newlfm

I have been using the `newlfm` package for many years for my correspondence.  Recently when I compile a letter, I get the following error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@zfancyhead ...1\hbox to\headwidth {\fancy@reset 
                                                  \@zfancyvbox \headheight 

{...

l.11 \begin{newlfm}
```

It is quite mysterious to me where this arises.  I am using an up-to-date TeX Live installation on a Mac, which I obtained from mactex.org. I am not aware of having changed anything myself, but the problem appears to have cropped up as a result of doing a MacTeX update at some point to keep up-to-date.

Any advice would be appreciated. I have a substantial base of correspondence that relies on `newlfm`!

Source file:

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
%\newlfmP{letrh=cmu}

\begin{document}
\addrto{}
\greetto{}
\begin{newlfm}



\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.10.10)  10 OCT 2017 14:21
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**bug
(./bug.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.14> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newlfm/newlfm.cls
Document Class: newlfm 2009/04/10 v9.4 Letter-Fax-Memo LaTeX Document Class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newlfm/setdim.sty
Package: setdim 2009/04/10 v9.4 Address macros
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty
Package: fancyhdr 2017/06/30 v3.9a Extensive control of page headers and footer
s
\f@nch@headwidth=\skip41
\f@nch@O@elh=\skip42
\f@nch@O@erh=\skip43
\f@nch@O@olh=\skip44
\f@nch@O@orh=\skip45
\f@nch@O@elf=\skip46
\f@nch@O@erf=\skip47
\f@nch@O@olf=\skip48
\f@nch@O@orf=\skip49
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty
Package: eso-pic 2015/07/21 v2.0g eso-pic (RN)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2017/06/24 v1.0g Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty
Package: setspace 2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lastpage/lastpage.sty
Package: lastpage 2015/03/29 v1.2m Refers to last page's name (HMM; JPG)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count79
\calc@Bcount=\count80
\calc@Adimen=\dimen102
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen103
\calc@Askip=\skip50
\calc@Bskip=\skip51
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count81
\calc@Cskip=\skip52
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 99.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen104
\Gin@req@width=\dimen105
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty
Package: rotating 2016/08/11 v2.16d rotated objects in LaTeX
\c@r@tfl@t=\count82
\rotFPtop=\skip53
\rotFPbot=\skip54
\rot@float@box=\box26
\rot@mess@toks=\toks15
)
\@addr@fr@sk@b=\skip55
\@addr@fr@sk@a=\skip56
\@addr@to@sk@b=\skip57
\@addr@to@sk@a=\skip58
\@blka@b=\skip59
\@blka@a=\skip60
\@blkb@b=\skip61
\@blkb@a=\skip62
\@blkc@b=\skip63
\@blkc@a=\skip64
\@caption@skip@above=\skip65
\@caption@skip@below=\skip66
\@cello@h=\skip67
\@cello@w=\skip68
\@cello@d=\skip69
\@cello@l=\skip70
\@dt@sk@b=\skip71
\@dt@sk@a=\skip72
\@Dth@H@L=\skip73
\@Dth@H@C=\skip74
\@Dth@H@R=\skip75
\@Dth@F@L=\skip76
\@Dth@F@C=\skip77
\@Dth@F@R=\skip78
\@Dth@h@l=\skip79
\@Dth@h@c=\skip80
\@Dth@h@r=\skip81
\@Dth@f@l=\skip82
\@Dth@f@c=\skip83
\@Dth@f@r=\skip84
\@greet@to@sk@b=\skip85
\@greet@to@sk@a=\skip86
\@Hgt@Head=\skip87
\@Hrw=\skip88
\@hrw=\skip89
\@extr@hor=\skip90
\@Frw=\skip91
\@frw=\skip92
\@Hgt@Foot=\skip93
\@Hgt@head=\skip94
\@Hgt@foot=\skip95
\@Hgt@H@L=\skip96
\@Hgt@H@C=\skip97
\@Hgt@H@R=\skip98
\@Hgt@F@L=\skip99
\@Hgt@F@C=\skip100
\@Hgt@F@R=\skip101
\@Hgt@h@l=\skip102
\@Hgt@h@c=\skip103
\@Hgt@h@r=\skip104
\@Hgt@f@l=\skip105
\@Hgt@f@c=\skip106
\@Hgt@f@r=\skip107
\@lab@bl=\skip108
\@lab@pl=\skip109
\@lab@pw=\skip110
\@lab@bh=\skip111
\@lab@bw=\skip112
\@lab@th=\skip113
\@lab@lm=\skip114
\@marg@lt=\skip115
\@marg@rt=\skip116
\@marg@tp=\skip117
\@marg@bt=\skip118
\@marg@tp@a=\skip119
\@marg@bt@a=\skip120
\@marg@bt@b=\skip121
\@marg@tp@b=\skip122
\@marg@tp@s=\skip123
\@marg@lt@r=\skip124
\@marg@lt@l=\skip125
\@marg@rt@r=\skip126
\@marg@rt@l=\skip127
\@marg@lt@tp@d=\skip128
\@marg@rt@tp@d=\skip129
\@Min@Hgt@Head=\skip130
\@Min@Hgt@head=\skip131
\@Min@Hgt@Foot=\skip132
\@Min@Hgt@foot=\skip133
\@Min@Hgt@Right=\skip134
\@Min@Hgt@right=\skip135
\@Min@Hgt@Left=\skip136
\@Min@Hgt@left=\skip137
\@Plg=\skip138
\@Pwd=\skip139
\@plg=\skip140
\@pwd=\skip141
\@post@sig@sp@a=\skip142
\@post@sig@sp@b=\skip143
\@pre@memo@sp=\skip144
\@post@memo@sp=\skip145
\@sig@sp=\skip146
\@text@width=\skip147
\@sig@sk@a=\skip148
\@sig@sk@b=\skip149
\@sig@sk@c=\skip150
\@sig@sk@r=\skip151
\@cls@sk@a=\skip152
\@cls@sk@b=\skip153
\@text@height=\skip154
\@unpr@tp=\skip155
\@unpr@bm=\skip156
\@unpr@rt=\skip157
\@unpr@lt=\skip158
\@util=\skip159
\@utila=\skip160
\@utilb=\skip161
\@utilc=\skip162
\@utild=\skip163
\@utile=\skip164
\@utilf=\skip165
\@utilg=\skip166
\@utilh=\skip167
\@utili=\skip168
\@utilj=\skip169
\@utilk=\skip170
\@utill=\skip171
\@xda=\skip172
\@xdb=\skip173
\@xdc=\skip174
\@xdd=\skip175
\@xde=\skip176
\@xdf=\skip177
\@xdg=\skip178
\@xdh=\skip179
\@xdi=\skip180
\@sig@box@a=\box27
\b@addr@fr=\box28
\b@addr@to=\box29
\@x@c=\box30
\@x@l=\box31
\@x@r=\box32
\fba=\box33
\adrfr=\box34
\adrto=\box35
\@sig@box@b=\box36
\@sig@box@c=\box37
\@sig@box@d=\box38
\@sig@box@e=\box39
\@sig@box@f=\box40
\@sig@box@g=\box41
\@sig@box@h=\box42
\@sig@box@i=\box43
\@sig@box@j=\box44
\@rest@ltr=\box45
\@resta@ltr=\box46
\@restb@ltr=\box47
\@restc@ltr=\box48
\@restd@ltr=\box49
\@reste@ltr=\box50
\c@@c@pos=\count83
\c@figure=\count84
\c@table=\count85
\c@@sig@tot=\count86
\c@@lab@tot@row=\count87
\c@@lab@tot@col=\count88
\c@@lab@cnt@row=\count89
\c@@lab@cnt@col=\count90
\@nlfm@addr=\count91
\@nlfm@util=\count92
\@nlfm@uta=\count93
\@nlfm@utb=\count94

All language information must be in newlfm.cls
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/letter.cls
Document Class: letter 2014/09/29 v1.2z Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\longindentation=\dimen106
\indentedwidth=\dimen107
\labelcount=\count95
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newlfm/addrset.sty
Package: addrset 2009/04/10 v9.4 Address macros
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/afterpage.sty
Package: afterpage 2014/10/28 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)
\AP@output=\toks16
\AP@partial=\box51
\AP@footins=\box52
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/envlab/envlab.sty
Package: envlab 1997/07/16 v1.2 Envelopes and Labels
Package envlab Info: Envelopes & Labels package: found makelabels...
(envlab)             Seems everything is OK. Good luck. on input line 58.
\@envelopeposition=\count96
\PSEnvelopeTray=\toks17
\EnvelopeWidth=\skip181
\EnvelopeHeight=\skip182
\EnvelopeTopMargin=\skip183
\EnvelopeLeftMargin=\skip184
\LabelWidth=\skip185
\LabelHeight=\skip186
\LabelTopMargin=\skip187
\LabelLeftMargin=\skip188
\LabelRightMargin=\skip189
\c@LabelMaxCol=\count97
\c@LabelMaxRow=\count98
\FromAddressTopMargin=\skip190
\FromAddressLeftMargin=\skip191
\FromAddressHeight=\skip192
\FromAddressWidth=\skip193
\ToAddressTopMargin=\skip194
\ToAddressLeftMargin=\skip195
\ToAddressWidth=\skip196

Loading configuration file envlab.cfg
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/envlab/envlab.cfg
File: envlab.cfg 1997/07/16 v1.2 Envelopes and Labels
)
\c@LabelCountCol=\count99
\c@LabelCountRow=\count100
\c@LabelOffsetCol=\count101
\c@LabelOffsetRow=\count102
\@numreturnlabels=\count103
\@zipcode=\toks18
\@zipcodesum=\count104
\@barcodewidth=\skip197
\@barcodeLheight=\skip198
\@barcodeSheight=\skip199
\@barcodeskip=\skip256
\@addr@cap=\toks19
)
The default definition for memosec is used. File memosec.tex doesn't exist.
Press release definitions stored in newlfm.cls
faxpage definitions stored in newlfm.cls
Reading default letter definitions from letrinfo.tex
(/Users/rwh/Library/texmf/tex/latex/rh/letrinfo.tex
\CMUlogo=\box53
<CMU_logo_horiz_red.png, id=1, 728.4816pt x 65.5248pt>
File: CMU_logo_horiz_red.png Graphic file (type png)
<use CMU_logo_horiz_red.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: CMU_logo_horiz_red.png  used on input line 2. on input
 line 2.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 254.97238pt x 22.934pt on input line 2
.

Overfull \hbox (2.97238pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 2--2
[][] 
 []

\RHsig=\box54
<rhsig.jpg, id=3, 279.31378pt x 100.59203pt>
File: rhsig.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
<use rhsig.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: rhsig.jpg  used on input line 5. on input line 5.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 184.34766pt x 66.39093pt on input line
 5.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \@texttop on input line 1884.
\@rep@th=\dimen108
\@rep@tw=\dimen109
\@rep@om=\dimen110
\@rep@em=\dimen111
\@rep@cs=\dimen112
\@rep@tm=\dimen113
\@rep@hh=\dimen114
\@rep@hs=\dimen115
\@rep@fs=\dimen116
) (./bug.aux)
\openout1 = `bug.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box55

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count105
\scratchdimen=\dimen117
\scratchbox=\box56
\nofMPsegments=\count106
\nofMParguments=\count107
\everyMPshowfont=\toks20
\MPscratchCnt=\count108
\MPscratchDim=\dimen118
\MPnumerator=\count109
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count110
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks21
) (/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
38.
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.pdf,.png,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PDF,.PNG,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 456.

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
Package lastpage Info: Please have a look at the pageslts package at
(lastpage)             https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts
(lastpage)             ! on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 7.

! Undefined control sequence.
\@zfancyhead ...1\hbox to\headwidth {\fancy@reset 
                                                  \@zfancyvbox \headheight {...
l.7 \begin{newlfm}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...arboxrestore \raggedright \f@ncyolh 
                                                  \@@par 
l.7 \begin{newlfm}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...@parboxrestore \centering \f@ncyolh 
                                                  \@@par 
l.7 \begin{newlfm}

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...parboxrestore \raggedleft \f@ncyorh 
                                                  \@@par 
l.7 \begin{newlfm}

? 

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 7

 []

[1


{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

AED: lastpage setting LastPage
(./bug.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4261 strings out of 492990
 56404 string characters out of 6132635
 137159 words of memory out of 5000000
 7773 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4237 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,11n,45p,266b,530s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on bug.pdf (1 page, 12001 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 15 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 7 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 11 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Can you include even just a minimal document that replicates this behaviour? And perhaps even a `.log` so we can figure out where the problem may lie?

Comment: Gladly, thanks.  How do I attach files here?

Comment: \documentclass{newlfm}
\newlfmP{letrh=cmu}

\begin{document}
\addrto{}
\greetto{}
\begin{newlfm}



\end{newlfm}
\end{document}

Comment: .log file is too large for a comment, but perhaps the source is sufficient.

Comment: bug persists even if the \newlfmP{letrh=cmu} line is deleted, which would leave behind a bare template for using newlfm.

Comment: You can [edit your post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/395504/edit), or paste content to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) and provide a link here.

Comment: Updated post with source and log files.

Comment: I [reformatted your code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and also added an answer to [this linked duplicate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395529/5764). Hopefully it solves your problem. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: ...then consider up-voting the answer so we can close this as a duplicate. It can only be closed if the linked question has an positive-scoring answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class appears to be broken  by a change in one of its dependencies (`fancyhdr`), even taking the first example from `textdoc newlfm` gives the same error.

```
  \documentclass[stdletter]{newlfm}
  \nameto{George Bush} \addrto{\parbox{2in}{The White House \\ Washington, DC}}
  \namefrom{Paul Thompson} \addrfrom{\parbox{2in}{The Pink House \\ Belleville, IL}}
  \begin{document}
  \closeline{Sincerely yours,} \greetto{Dear Mr. Bush,}
  \begin{newlfm}
  How are the azaleas?
  \end{newlfm}
  \end{document}
```

gives

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@zfancyhead ...1\hbox to\headwidth {\fancy@reset 
                                                  \@zfancyvbox \headheight {...
l.7       \begin{newlfm}
```

This is a duplicate of [Undefined control sequence error on \fancy@reset, \f@ncyolh and \f@ncyorh when using newlfm class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377454/undefined-control-sequence-error-on-fancyreset-fncyolh-and-fncyorh-when-u) but that has no answer either

a bit long for a comment so cw answer

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem.  Bad programming practice in newlfm.cls.