# I am looking for the solution of the spacing problem

Tags: spacing, newlfm

I was looking for a cover letter template. Then I found a example adapted from Matthew J. Miller's template. Moreover, the template is as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno]{newlfm}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{url}

\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000


\namefrom{Matthew J.\ Miller}


\greetto{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

I am writing to apply for the position of assistant
professor in Clemson University's Computer Science Department.  I plan to receive my
Ph.D.\ degree from the University of Illinois at
Urbana-Champaign in Summer of 2006.  My adviser is
Prof.\ Nitin H.\ Vaidya, and my general areas of interest
include wireless and sensor network performance and security.
 Having many friends and family in the area, I would be
most enthused to return to the South permanently by accepting
a position at your institution.

In my graduate work, I focus on the design of
energy-efficient protocols and secure key distribution.
More specifically, I have explored various techniques at
multiple layers of the network stack to effectively reduce
the energy consumption of wireless communication.  In security,
my work was the first to propose leveraging channel diversity
for sensor network key distribution.  My research appears in 
the \textit{IEEE Transactions on Mobile Computing} journal as
well as \textit{Infocom 2006} and \textit{ICDCS 2005},
prestigious conferences in the areas of networking and distributed
systems, respectively.

Enclosed is my curriculum vitae (including a list of
publications), contact information for my references, a research
statement, and a teaching statement.  All of my publications and
presentations are available at:

\url{http://www.crhc.uiuc.edu/~mjmille2/publications/}

Please let me know if there are any other materials
or information that will assist you in processing my application.

Thank you for your consideration.  I look forward to
hearing from you.

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

But when I run it, I found the gaps between 'the line' and 'Dear sir or Madam'.
[image]

Please help how to erase the gap.
Thanking in advanced.

Comment: The gap is caused by the address-from on the right. And perhaps users will need this patch: [Undefined control sequence error on `\fancy@reset`, `\f@ncyolh` and `\f@ncyorh `when using newlfm class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395529/79060).

Comment: Now I have cleared the address from on the right. But the following gap is still there. If you help then I will be very grateful to you.

Comment: can you give your question a sensible title? the current one doesn't help anyone searching and could apply to every question on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd forego [`newlfm`](//ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) (not updated since 2009) in lieu of the default `article` class. `newlfm` (like other letter-writing classes) requires you to specify a number of components within the preamble when it would be far easier/better to just write them out within the code as and when you need them.

Here's a quick example that provides a no-nonsense interface:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{url}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{.25\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

Dear Sir or Madam,

\bigskip

I am writing to apply for the position of assistant
professor in Clemson University's Computer Science 
Department.  I plan to receive my
Ph.D.\ degree from the University of Illinois at
Urbana-Champaign in Summer of 2006.  My adviser is
Prof.\ Nitin H.\ Vaidya, and my general areas of interest
include wireless and sensor network performance and security.
 Having many friends and family in the area, I would be
most enthused to return to the South permanently by accepting
a position at your institution.

In my graduate work, I focus on the design of
energy-efficient protocols and secure key distribution.
More specifically, I have explored various techniques at
multiple layers of the network stack to effectively reduce
the energy consumption of wireless communication.  In security,
my work was the first to propose leveraging channel diversity
for sensor network key distribution.  My research appears in 
the \textit{IEEE Transactions on Mobile Computing} journal as
well as \textit{Infocom 2006} and \textit{ICDCS 2005},
prestigious conferences in the areas of networking and distributed
systems, respectively.

Enclosed is my curriculum vitae (including a list of
publications), contact information for my references, a research
statement, and a teaching statement.  All of my publications and
presentations are available at:

\url{http://www.crhc.uiuc.edu/~mjmille2/publications/}

Please let me know if there are any other materials
or information that will assist you in processing my application.

Thank you for your consideration.  I look forward to
hearing from you.

\bigskip

\mbox{}\hfill Sincerely,

\vspace{7\baselineskip}

\mbox{}\hfill Matthew J.\ Miller

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the user manual of `newlfm`, Table 6, using `\addrfromskipafter{<length>}` works. The following example shows the effect of `\addrfromskipafter{0pt}`.

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno]{newlfm}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% apply patch from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395529
\patchcmd{\@zfancyhead}{\fancy@reset}{\f@nch@reset}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@nch@olh}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@set@em@up}{\f@ncyorh}{\f@nch@orh}{}{}
\makeatother


\namefrom{Matthew J.\ Miller}


\greetto{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}

% This sets internal length \@addr@fr@sk@a, which is initially 36pt.
\addrfromskipafter{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

I am writing to apply for the position of assistant
professor in Clemson University's Computer Science Department.  I plan to receive my
Ph.D.\ degree from the University of Illinois at
Urbana-Champaign in Summer of 2006.  My adviser is
Prof.\ Nitin H.\ Vaidya, and my general areas of interest
include wireless and sensor network performance and security.
 Having many friends and family in the area, I would be
most enthused to return to the South permanently by accepting
a position at your institution.

In my graduate work, I focus on the design of
energy-efficient protocols and secure key distribution.
More specifically, I have explored various techniques at
multiple layers of the network stack to effectively reduce
the energy consumption of wireless communication.  In security,
my work was the first to propose leveraging channel diversity
for sensor network key distribution.  My research appears in 
the \textit{IEEE Transactions on Mobile Computing} journal as
well as \textit{Infocom 2006} and \textit{ICDCS 2005},
prestigious conferences in the areas of networking and distributed
systems, respectively.

Enclosed is my curriculum vitae (including a list of
publications), contact information for my references, a research
statement, and a teaching statement.  All of my publications and
presentations are available at:

\url{http://www.crhc.uiuc.edu/~mjmille2/publications/}

Please let me know if there are any other materials
or information that will assist you in processing my application.

Thank you for your consideration.  I look forward to
hearing from you.

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But can I remove the gap a little more? But it should not effect the starting of the consecutive page. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @UnknownUser Just use smaller (negative) dimension instead of `0pt`. I am not familiar with `newlfm`, so may not understand "should not effect the starting of the consecutive page". You can open a new question if new problem is encountered, or comment under my answer with examples updated if that seems to be related to the code I gave.

Comment: @UnknownUser I might get your point. If so, then what you want is to move some vertical spaces from above the text to below, is it?

Comment: @ muzimuzhi Z sorry for the late reply. I followed  your advice about  the negative dimension instead '0pt'. But I have failed to provide the same environment to the second page as the first page.

Comment: @UnknownUser On the second page, there is _no_ vertical space between headline and main text, by default. And I think to typeset a letter, you can just start from `article` class, hence get rid of learning and configuring `newlfm`.